# Retrigerr RevealWrapper in NextJs upon State change

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using next-reveal to access the RevealWrapper component. This works well when the page loads, but when the state of currentProduct changes, the new product loads without the RevealWrapper animations. I'm trying to find a way to use the same animation each time the content changes.

```
<RevealWrapper origin={'left'} delay={0}>
              <ContentWrapper>
                <Title>{currentProduct?.title}</Title>
              </ContentWrapper>
</RevealWrapper>



  useEffect(() => {
const interval = setInterval(() => 
setCurrentIndex(currentIndex => carouselTimer(currentIndex + 1)), 2000);
setCurrentProduct(products[currentIndex]);
return () => clearInterval(interval);
```

})

The carouselTimer function just checks for out of bounds as the index changes.

https://github.com/ritmillio/next-reveal

I've tried loading the entire content based on a boolean but this doesn't reset the wrapper for some reason. I'm not sure how else to trigger it.